# How to create instance of object from prototype method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it possible to create an instance of an object from it's prototype if the prototype is being used for multiple sublclasses?

For example, if I have:

```
var BaseClass = Backbone.Model.extend({
   createNewForMap: function(map) {
     // Here I would like to create a new instance of the
     // class that the method is being called for.
   }
});

var ClassOne = BaseClass.extend({});
var ClassTwo = BaseClass.extend({});
```

Then, somewhere in my application code, I want to be able to call:

```
var model = ClassOne.createNewForMap(map);
```

or

```
var model = ClassTwo.createNewForMap(map);
```

And have `model` be an instance of `ClassOne` or `ClassTwo`.

Comment: `var model = new ClassOne()` then `model.createNewForMap(map)`?

Comment: why can't you just do `new ClassOne()` and `new ClassTwo()` to create their instances..?

Comment: @TJ Or just use [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) if you only have an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to define a static method on the `BaseClass`, that will serve as a factory function for it or any children classes, that inherit it.

[Backbone.Model.extend](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend) allows you to specify so-called `classProperties`, that might be considered as something similair to static methods from conservative OOP programming.

```js
var BaseClass = Backbone.Model.extend({}, {
  
  // A static method for invoking constructor function.
  createNewForMap: function(map) {
    return new this;
  }
});

var ClassOne = BaseClass.extend({
  initialize: function() { this.foo = 'bar' }
});

var ClassTwo = BaseClass.extend({
  initialize: function() { this.foo = 'buz' }
});

console.log(ClassTwo.createNewForMap().foo); // buz
```

```html
<script src="//underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property to get a reference to an object's "class":

> **Object.prototype.constructor**
>
> Returns a reference to the `Object` function that created the instance's prototype. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the function itself, not a string containing the function's name.

So you can say things like:

```
createNewForMap: function(map) {
  var obj = new this.constructor();
  //...
}
```

and `obj` will be the same type of thing as `this`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/avk4z6Le/